# Looking for help creating 15 min appointments, Currently hard coded for 1 hour

Tags: java, javafx, time

First time post - I'm newer to java/JavaFx

I'm trying to get my code to save in 15 min incrementalist. The project has an Observable List that houses selectable appointment times.

ApptAddController.java

```
private final ObservableList<String> times = FXCollections.observableArrayList("8:00 AM", "9:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "1:00 PM", "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM", "4:00 PM");
```

ApptDB.Java

The "times" selected goes to the "saveAppt" method

```
public static boolean saveAppt(int id, String type, String contact, String location, String date, String time) {
        //Time stamp for booking times
        String tsStart = createTimeStamp(date, time, location, true);
        String tsEnd = createTimeStamp(date, time, location, false);
        try {
            //get date for Appointment createDate
            DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String nowString = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC()).format(dt);
            Statement statement = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
            //Query
            String queryInsertOne = "INSERT INTO appointment(customerId, type, contact, location, start, end,  createDate, lastUpdateBy, createdBy) values ('" + id + "', '" + type + "', '" + contact + "', '" + location + "','" + tsStart + "','" + tsEnd + "','" + nowString + "','" + UserDB.getCurrentUser() + "','" + UserDB.getCurrentUser() + "')";
            int updateOne = statement.executeUpdate(queryInsertOne);         
            return true;
       } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The createTimeStamp method is hard coded in the following method with the "00":

```
public static String createTimeStamp(String date, String time, String location, boolean startMode) {
        String t = time.split(":")[0];
        int baseH = Integer.parseInt(t);
        if(baseH < 8) {
            baseH += 12;
        }
        if(!startMode) {
            baseH += 1;
        }
        String baseD = String.format("%s %02d:%s", date, baseH, "00");
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm");
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(baseD, dtf);
        ZoneId zid;
        zid = TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId();
           ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zid);
        ZonedDateTime utcDate = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        ldt = utcDate.toLocalDateTime();
        Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt); 
        return ts.toString();
    }
```

Id like to have the appointments be 15 min incrementals. The user will select times at random (8:00, 8:15, 8:30, 8:45). How do I get this code to detect what the user selects and puts int in the database accordingly. If I change "00" to "15" it will hard code every appt for 15 after.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you using the `ObservableList`? In most cases it's preferrable to store the actual data, not a string representation of it. Furthermore converting to a time object to a string only to parse the string as time object is pretty surely not a good way of approaching this.

Comment: As an aside format pattern letters are case sensitive, and you don't want uppercase `YYYY`. It appears to work, but will surprise you around New Year.

Comment: Don't concatenate your values into you SQL string. Use `?` placeholders.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Judging by your comment on one of the answers: looks like you need to invest some time in _learning_ (as in reading and understanding) the basics, the info page of the java/javafx tags have references to tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not able to follow your code well. So here's some general advice. I should say up front, managing appointments and schedules is a surprisingly complicated problem domain.

You seem to be focused on strings rather than appropriate data types, a common issue with new programmers. Learn to **use smart objects, not dumb strings**. Notice that none of the code shown below involves strings, except for presentation to users. Values are exchanged with the database as objects, without the use of strings.

Java offers an industry-leading assortment of date-time classes, in the *java.time* packages. So use them. `LocalTime` represents a time-of-day. `LocalDate` represents a date-only, without time-of-day, and without time zone.

For data-entry on the time of appointment, you should be collecting an hour and a minute. Work internally with 24-hour clock [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) objects.

```
List< LocalTime > hourTimes = 
    List.of( 
        LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 9 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 11 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 12 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 13 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ,
        LocalTime.of( 16 , 0 ) 
    )
;
```

If your audience expects a [12-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock), present their display with a custom formatter. If your audience expects a 12-hour clock, present their display with a custom formatter.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter formatterHourOfDay = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "h a" ).withLocale ( locale ) ;
String output = hourTimes.get( 7 ).format( formatterHourOfDay ) ;
```

See similar [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/vh7Gdl).

> 3 PM

Note that *java.time* uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So you can freely use the `LocalTime` object directly from the master list with no need to copy, no need to worry about its values being changed out from under your feet. This also means you can use *java.time* objects across threads, as they are designed to be [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Keep a list of the possible minutes.

```
List< Integer > minutes = List.of( 0 , 15 , 30 , 45 ) ;
```

In you user-interface, let the use pick one of those four values, to be mated with their choice from `hourTimes` above.

Put these values together for your time-of-day to make a new [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime localTime = hourTimes.get( 7 ).plusMinutes( minutes.get( 2 ) ) ;  // Adding 0, 15, 30, or 45 minutes to the on-the-hour `LocalTime` object, resulting in another `LocalTime` object.
```

Combine the time-of-day with your intended date to get a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of( localDate , localTime ) ;
```

Store that in a database column of SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. (that was "WITHOUT", not "WITH")

Generally best to use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) in SQL rather than string-combining.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDateTime ) ;
```

In addition, record the intended time zone for that appointment. There is a data type in Java for this, [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html). But not in SQL. So record the zone name as text in your database.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , z.toString() ) ;  // Record name of zone as text.
```

By the way, no need to pass when the record was created or last updated. You should be configuring your database to set those value automatically on the server-side.

Separate your business logic from your user-interface. Notice that none of my code above relates to [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX).

Define a class just for the appointment. This class should know only the needs of an appointment, the business rules for what defines a valid appointment. This class should know nothing about the database, nor the user-interface.

I do not understand what you are trying to do with time zones in your use of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). It seems you are trying to form a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object. That is the wrong way to go for two reasons. First, that class is one of the **terrible legacy date-time classes** supplanted by *java.time*; never use it. Second, that is the wrong way to book appointments. Future appointments should be recorded as two separate parts, (a) date-with-time-of-day and (b) time zone.

Politicians around the world have shown a penchant for frequently changing the offset of the time zones under their jurisdiction. They do so with little, or even no, forewarning. So if you booked 3:45 PM for next January as a moment, as a specific point on the timeline, the time-of-day for that zone's wall-clock time might be changed by then, with 3:45 PM becoming 3:15 PM or 4:45 PM. Imagine if your software booked an appointment for the specific moment that *was* 3:45 PM *before* the zone changed its offset-from-UTC. The customers keeping their appointments will be appearing at 3 PM on the current wall-clock time while your appointment book software will show them as early (or late). To avoid this problem, **do not schedule appointments as a moment**, keep the date-with-time-of-day ([`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)) separated from the time zone (`ZoneId`).

Combine the two (date-with-time-of-day & time zone) only when building out a schedule where you need specific moments.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( zoneNameFromDatabase ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDateTimeFromDatabase.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you need to see that moment in UTC, adjust by extracting a `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

But do not store either the `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` for the future. Store them only after the fact, when recording history. And even then, you record `OffsetDateTime`, as oddly the JDBC spec does not require support for `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`. You would store that `OffsetDateTime` object in a column of SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` ("WITH", not "WITHOUT" as seen above).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;  // Record history as a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy & modern) and in standard SQL.]

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you can and should put `LocalTime` objects in your `ObservableList`. Rather than `String` objects. If so, do that.

Also use SQL datatype `time` for the times in your database (they may already be, I didn't notice this information in your question). Pass the `LocalTime` object to your database using a `PrepatedStatement`. For example:

```
    yourPreparedStatement.setObject(5, startLocalTime);
    yourPreparedStatement.setObject(6, endLocalTime);
```

Do similarly for date, etc., only using the appropriate types both on the Java and the SQL side.

To calculate end time as 15 minutes after start time:

```
    LocalTime endLocalTime = startLocalTime.plusMinutes(15);
```

I know I am not giving you complete code, but I hope it will get you a step or two further.

Comment: Hi, I don't suppose you can elaborate where the suggested code would fit/replace. Apologies, I am new with Java and still working on my sea legs. I am sort of following what you are saying here.

Comment: For prepared statements and how to pass parameters to them, please search, it’s described in very many places. And yes, what I am suggesting entails pretty much of a rewrite of your code, so the lines from the answer don’t really simply fit/replace into the code in your question. I may or may not find time to elaborate later.